# Use of deleted function error with qAsConst

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I'm writing a simply loop which iterates through the keys in a QMap as show below:

```
  for (const auto &id: qAsConst(m_myMap.keys())) {
    // Do something which does not affect m_myMap
  }
```

Compiling the loop generates an error:

> use of deleted function 'void qAsConst(const T&&)[with
> T=QList]'

Without the qAsConst I get the error:

> Allocating an unneeded temporary container.

I thought the whole point of qAsConst was to avoid creating the temporary container.  But I don' understand the message - why is it calling a deleted function?  How do I fix this to get rid of the error / warning?

Answer (score 2):

It means that you create a container with this statement: `m_myMap.keys()` for no good reason. `qAsConst()`  does not prevent the unneeded allocations. `const T& QMap::const_iterator::operator*() const` returns a value, the range-loop with keys cannot be used.

Use a usual loop like below

```
for (auto it = m_myMap.begin(); it != m_myMap.end(); ++i) {
  // it->key();
}
```

---

The first my answer is wrong.

```
for (const auto& [id, value]: m_myMap) {
  // Do something which does not affect m_myMap
}
```

Comment: Iterator solution should use const iterators to avoid possible CoW detach.

Comment: The 2nd solution should use `qAsConst` to avoid possible CoW detach.

Comment: @hyde The question lacks of a [mcve], `m_myMap` might be const and `qAsConst` is unnecessary.

Comment: @273K using `qAsConst` on already const container does not cause any harm and is no-op. It is better to be sure (i.e. use `qAsConst` on const contaiiner) than to forget (and have unwanted container detachment).

Comment: Likelyhood of a member variable map being const is low enough, that the default assumption has to be, that it isn't const, if it isn't explicitly said to be const. Much like how C++ language has it, actually.

Answer (score 2):

`QMap::keys()` returns a QList by *value*.

`qAsConst` can't be applied to this *rvalue* because its lifetime ends when `qAsConst` returns. This is why this is prevented on purpose, and you get that error about deleted function.

A solution is to use a temp variable:

```
const auto ids  = m_myMap.keys();
for (auto &id: ids) {
    ....
```

Now `keys` is const already, so `const` or `qAsConst` would be redundant, it's already so.

---

Note that using a const iterator would be more efficient, avoiding *O(log n)* QMap lookup every round.